# About how multiple tf.layer.conv2d connect between each other

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, theory

I have a doubt about how 2 2d convolutions connect with each other. I understand the convolution concept and that x amount of filters produce x amount of feature maps, but what happen when, for example, you have 16 feature maps and you apply a convolution with 8 filters? does each of the 8 filters convolute with each of the 16 feature maps? and then they add the 16 resulting feature maps resulting from each of the 8 filters? or what is the process involved? Thank you. Below you can see a diagram of what I want to know.

[image]

Dimensions of x1 and x2:

**x1: (?,128,256,16)**

**x2: (?,128,256,8)**

what is the process to go from x1 to x2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your misunderstanding is that you are thinking about `[h, w]` filter kernels.

But in fact, these are 8-times `[h, w, channels_in]` filters.

For each of the 8 output-channels, you have a filter of size [h, w, 16]. Hence, the entire memory consumption is [h, w, channels-in, channels-out] (exactly as stated in the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/conv2d)). A good way to visualize it is to think about 8-times having 16 separate `[h, w]` filter-kernel, which 16 outputs are summed up.

Comment: Then why would you like to have control of those variables (channels_in, channels_out)?  tf.layers.conv2d doesn't seem to have a parameter for those variables.

Comment: It does! Channels-in is from the input shape. And channels-out is a parameter.

Comment: So the amount of parameters I'm training in the second layer is 16*8, is that right?